# Join tables showing unique values in each row

Tags: mysql, sql, join, database-design

I have 2 tables called cash and check

**CASH**

| cstm_id | cash_date | cash_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 20220529 | 50 |
| 101 | 20220530 | 100 |
| 102 | 20220601 | 50 |
| 102 | 20220603 | 75 |

**CHECK**

| cstm_id | check_date | check_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 20210525 | 150 |
| 101 | 20210812 | 25 |
| 102 | 20220210 | 25 |
| 102 | 20220603 | 20 |

I want to join the tables so I have unique values in each row without any duplication

**EXPECTED RESULT:**

| cstm_id | cash_date | cash_amount | check_date | check_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 20220529 | 50 | null | null |
| 101 | 20220530 | 100 | null | null |
| 101 | null | null | 20210525 | 150 |
| 101 | null | null | 20210812 | 25 |
| 102 | 20220601 | 50 | null | null |
| 102 | null | null | 20210110 | 25 |
| 102 | 20220603 | 75 | 20220603 | 20 |

What would be the most appropriate sql script for this output

Comment: You probably need to use a CROSS JOIN. I would suggest trying that and, if you are still facing issues, update your question with the sql that you’ve managed to write and the issue you are facing

Comment: What "order" do you want the results in?  Did you want the 'cash' and 'check' rows paired up, so there were no NULLs?

Answer (score 0):

One approach can be via full outer join -

```
select distinct * from (
   select c.*, c1.check_date, c1.check_amount
      from cash c left join check1 c1
      on c.cstm_id=c1.cstm_id
      and c.cash_date = c1.check_date
  union all
    select c1.cstm_id,c.cash_date,c.cash_amount, c1.check_date, c1.check_amount
      from cash c right join check1 c1
      on c.cstm_id=c1.cstm_id
      and c.cash_date = c1.check_date
 ) t;
```

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7oq5iDV47nokTpWQDo8kY8/1).

Comment: May as well remove the `DISTINCT` after `SELECT` and change `ALL` to `DISTINCT`.  (Probably no performance change.)